# knockoutjs: How to use boolean && in if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm developing knockoutjs, I want to use boolean in data-bind and here my code but it is not working

```
<p class="cmt-post" data-bind="if:deleteDate&&owner='1'">
     <span data-bind="text:deleteDate">
     </span>
 </p>
```

Comment: if deleteDate is an observable, I suppose it will always evaluate to true (because the object exists but is not executed)

Answer (score 1):

If `deleteDate` and `owner` are observables you need to evaluate them using `()`. Also you should use `===` instead of `=` as `===` is used to compare equality and will also ensure that the types are the same. I.e. `1 === '1'` will false whereas `1 == '1'` is true.

```
<p class="cmt-post" data-bind="if:deleteDate()&&owner()==='1'">
     <span data-bind="text:deleteDate">
     </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need double equals to compare equality (as you do in standard JS, otherwise it's an assignment):

```
 data-bind="if:deleteDate && owner == '1'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning owner value use `==` instead of `=`

```
<p class="cmt-post" data-bind="if:deleteDate&&owner == '1'">
   <span data-bind="text:deleteDate"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose You to separate any logic to a viewModel instead

So consider method in your view model for example:

```
function ViewModel(){

  this.delete_date_visible = ko.pureComputed(
      this.getDeleteDateVisible,
      this
  )
};

ViewModel.prototype.getDeleteDateVisible = function(){
   return this.deleteDate() && this.owner == '1'
}
```

In the view:

```
<span data-bind="if: delete_date_visible">...</span>
```

or even

```
<!-- ko if: delete_date_visible -->
<span>...</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

which looks cleaner i think.

The pure computed that is using view model's method because:

- you don't need to call it in the template
- the getter method could be re-used natively in the view model